# textfield validation fails in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, textfield

this is my first question here. I am not sure if I am writing it in a correct form.

I would like to validate TextField widget but it fails and throw an error.
here is how the code look like.

```
void surfaceCalc() {
    if(_length == '' && _length == null && _width == '' && _width == null){
      print('one of the field is empty');
    } else{
      final surfaceArea = double.parse(_length.text) *
        double.parse(_width.text);
    }
```

but the problem with this, that when i click on calculate button, it goes to this file **double_patch.dart** and highlight **invalid double**. as far as i understand, it throws and error because the text field is empty and has not been validated, it skips the validation and goes to calculation and throws an error. but if i type values in the textfield, it works fine.

**any help is highly appreciated**

Comment: it would be easier if could provide simple full widget . also the the `&&` might be replace with `||`

Comment: Can you include a full  sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?